# Exception not thrown through the function but directly caught

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

I have a function *Overwrite* which throw an exception when an object is locked by the user.

For now, my code is

```
 public class MyObject<T>
{
    //...other methods,...
    public void Overwrite(T value)
    {
        if (IsLocked)
            throw new Exception("You cannot touch the data you don't own");
        this.Value = value;
        OnUpdate?.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

I use several MyObject in my code and when the *IsLocked* is set to true, my exception is directly captured by the IDE in the *Overwrite* method. So, I cannot see where the error comes from (I mean, the line where I can find the faulty call to *Overwrite*.

See below :[image]

Where I want my exception is when I call MyObject.Overwrite(), then I can see the faulty line (and the faulty object).

I've tried several techniques like try-catch-throw,... but none work.

By the way, it's the first time I'm creating an Exception in CSharp and usually all the exceptions I caught in the past were unhandled at the faulty line...

**EDIT** : I expect more something like this :
[image]

Comment: Try to use **Call Stack** window. You can open it via Debug > Windows > Call Stack

Comment: I can see where comes from the error thanks to that tip. Is it possible to underline in yellow the faulty line via another trick ?

Comment: I've added an answer with a screenshot. Please try to double click on the line which my arrow points to.

Comment: please vote if my answer is useful.

Comment: I update to show you exactly what I would like. But your option to have the Call Stack help me also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Call Stack window. You can open it via Debug > Windows > Call Stack

[image: call stack]